# Undefines function get_field() on PLESK Schedulation Tasks

Tags: wordpress, scheduled-tasks, advanced-custom-fields, plesk

I'm trying to create a schedule script php from PLESK but i have a problem when i've use get_field() function from ACF.
Plesk retriew the error:
" PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_field()..... "

I have the same problem with all function called from Wordpress.

The code inside the PHP script is:

```
    $my_var = get_field('indirizzo_ip','options');
    echo $my_var;
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include these files at the top of your script and you`ll have all the WordPress functions available:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/path/to/your/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php');
require('/path/to/your/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
```

Regards Tom

Comment: Thanks dude! Work Fine! 
But it retrieve that notice: 
Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_PROTOCOL in /var/www/vhosts/my-site.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/load.php on line 16
Notice: Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD in /var/www/v
hosts/my-site.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 26

How i can't fix this?

Thanks alot

Comment: It is just a notice. It seems like the $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] variable is not pupulated to your script, but in line 18 it is set to "HTTP/1.0" for default. Just ignore it ;-)